# MongoDB update with condition

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm trying to update some field in my collection depending on a condition.

I want to set field `active` to `true` if the condition is `true` and to `false` otherwise

This is update without condition

```
db.consent.update(
{}, //match all
{
    $set: {
        "active": true
    }
}, 
{
    multi: true,
}

)
```

I would like to add a condition to update like this:

```
db.consent.update(
{},
$cond: {
    if: {

        $eq: ["_id", ObjectId("5714ce0a4514ef3ef68677fd")]

    },
    then: {
        $set: {
            "active": true
        }
    },
    else: {
        $set: {
            "active": false
        }
    }
}, 
{
    multi: true,
}
```

)

According to https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/ there is no `$cond` operator for update.

What are my options here to execute this update as a single command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB, conditional upserts or updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540103/mongodb-conditional-upserts-or-updates)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update/creation of a field based on another field:

```
// { a: "Hello", b: "World" }
// { a: "Olleh", b: "Dlrow" }
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [ { $set: { active: { $eq: [ "$a", "Hello" ] } } } ]
)
// { a: "Hello", b: "World", active: true  }
// { a: "Olleh", b: "Dlrow", active: false }
```

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update (in our case all documents).
- The second part `[ { $set: { active: { $eq: [ "$a", "Hello" ] } } } ]` is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline). [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator and an alias of `$addFields`. Then any aggregation operator can be used within the `$set` stage; in our case a conditional equality check on which depends the value to use for the new `active` field.

Answer (score 33):

We can do it using aggregation pipeline. Here i am updating male to female and female to male.

```
db.customer.updateMany(
   { },
   [
     { $set: { gender: { $switch: {
                           branches: [
                               { case: { $eq: [ "$gender", 'male' ] }, then: "female" },
                               { case: { $eq: [ "$gender", 'female' ] }, then: "male" }
                           ],
                           default: ""
     } } } }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 14):

<strike>You can't.</strike>

Mongo doesn't support combining fields, conditionals etc. in the update statement.

---

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551655/442351 below.

Comment: Not that I know of, just have to make two update calls.  One for the trues, one for the falses.

Comment: just for info, you can update the docs based on the condition but you cant write if else in query.

Answer (score 13):

You can update MongoDB document conditionally using [findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) or [findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db-collection-findoneandupdate) if you have MongoDB version 3.2+

Comment: From the documentation `The findAndModify command modifies and returns a single document` . So this would be good for one document only, but I need to update the entire collection. So I think I'm basically stuck with: 1) Two phase commit
2) 2 queries
3) Some other document, that would hold info about this one
4) Change the implementation

Answer (score 9):

Of course you can....
by running 2 queries

```
db.collection.update({condition}, { $set: { state } }, { multi: true });
db.collection.update({!condition}, { $set: { state } }, { multi: false });
```

for your example case

```
db.consent.update(
  {"_id": ObjectId("5714ce0a4514ef3ef68677fd")},
  { $set: { "active": true } });

db.consent.update(
  {"_id": {$ne: ObjectId("5714ce0a4514ef3ef68677fd")}},
  { $set: { "active": false } },
  { multi: true });
```

Comment: Here the `multi` option is for applying the modifier on multiple matching records and not as `$set` value. If you only want to update the first matching record, set `multi` to `false` (default), otherwise, explicitly mention `multi` as `true` to update all records.

Answer (score 5):

```
db.consent.update(
    {
       //YOUR CONDITIONAL HERE TO APLLAY UPDATE ONLY IF CONDITIONAL HAPPEN, SO THE "active": true WILL BE APPLY. 
    }, 
    {
       $set: {
         "active": true,
         "active2": FALSE,
       }
    }, 
    {
        multi: true,
    }
)
```

Comment: It may be a great answer but adding an explanation will make it useful to others