# Mongo Update Query on Array Index value matching

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

`student` collection look like below.

```
[{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "studentId" : "70133",
    "subjects" : [ 
        "Mathematics", 
        "Biology and Zoology"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "studentId" : "70134",
    "subjects" : [ 
        "Mathematics", 
        "English"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(3),
    "studentId" : "70135",
    "subjects" : [ 
        "English", 
        "Mathematics",
        "Chemistry"
    ]
}]);
```

I want to write a query which will update the student collection subject array values like this:

- If subject matches `English` have to be updated to **ENG**
- If subject matches `Biology` and `Zoology` have to be updated to **BAZ**
- If subject matches `Mathematics` have to be updated to **MAT**
- If subject matches `Chemistry` have to be updated to **CHM**

After update documents should look like below. How Can I achieve this.

```
[{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "studentId" : "70133",
    "subjects" : [ 
        "MAT", 
        "BAZ"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "studentId" : "70134",
    "subjects" : [ 
        "MAT", 
        "ENG"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(3),
    "studentId" : "70135",
    "subjects" : [ 
        "ENG", 
        "MAT",
        "CHM"
    ]
}]);
```

Comment: The answer depends upon which version of mongo are you using if you are looking for conditional updates then they are only [supported from v4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551655/2417602). Else you may have to write a script to do the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be done with multiple updates like:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "subjects" : { $in : [ "Mathematics" ] } },
    { $set: { "subjects.$" : "MAT" } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

See this page for more information regarding updating multiple document

> if **multi** is set to true, the db.collection.update() method updates all documents that meet the  criteria. The **multi** update operation may interleave with other read/write operations.

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#multi-parameter

Comment: Thank you Kevin, it worked with multiple Update queries." subjects.$ " here $ will get the index of that when condition part of the query?

Comment: You are welcome! The "subjects.$" is called the positional $ operator and acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document.