# How to use $cond in updateOne using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update a value in the mongodb depending on its previous value, if `null` (saved as string) then I will update it to a new value, otherwise I want to keep it as it is.
Here is my code:

```
User.updateOne({_id: user._id}, {$set: {
                        deviceId: {$cond: [{$eq: ['null']}, req.body.deviceId, 'null']}
                    }}, null, function (err, res){
                    if (err){
                        return done(err)
                    }else{
                        return done(null, user)
                    }
                })
```

But I get the following error (I believe it indicates that my syntax is not correct):

```
CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ '$cond': [ { '$eq': [Array] }, 'MYDEVICEID', 'null' ] }" (type Object) at path "deviceId"
    at model.Query.exec (D:\X_APP\XAPP_BACKEND\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4478:21)
    at _update (D:\X_APP\XAPP_BACKEND\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4330:11)
    at model.Query.Query.updateOne (D:\X_APP\XAPP_BACKEND\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4229:10)
    at _update (D:\X_APP\XAPP_BACKEND\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3834:16)
    at Function.updateOne (D:\X_APP\XAPP_BACKEND\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3770:10)
    at file:///D:/X_APP/XAPP_BACKEND/middlewares/userMiddleware.js:24:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I searched and saw many applications using the Aggregation but is it possible to achieve it using my approach `updateOne` in mongoose? if yes, what is the issue with my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$cond` is an aggregation operator you can not use in a simple update query,

> *if null (saved as string) then I will update it to a new value, otherwise I want to keep it as it is.*

If you are trying to update a single field, i would suggest a simple approach,

You can check the condition in the query part if `deviceId` is null then update new `deviceId` otherwise it will ignore update operation,

```
await User.updateOne(
  { 
    _id: user._id,
    deviceId: "null"
  }, 
  {
    $set: {
      deviceId: req.body.deviceId
    }
  }, 
  null, 
  function (err, res){
    if (err){
      return done(err)
    }else{
      return done(null, user)
    }
  }
);
```

---

Second, as per your try, you can achieve by [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

```
await User.updateOne(
  { _id: user._id }, 
  [{
    $set: {
      deviceId: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$deviceId", "null"] },
          req.body.deviceId,
          "null" // or you can use "$deviceId"
        ]
      }
    }
  }], 
  null, 
  function (err, res){
    if (err){
      return done(err)
    }else{
      return done(null, user)
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach is better for me even when I need to update more than one field with different conditions.

Comment: I have added second approach as well as per your need.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use `$cond` with the update, MongoDB doesn't allow this.

But you still can achieve this by using this way: [MongoDB update with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698569/mongodb-update-with-condition/56551655#56551655)

Comment: I just saw that `collection.update()` is deprecated in mongoose, so is there another way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CollectionName.findByIdAndUpdate()` it's works for me.

```js
router.post('/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  
  try {
    /*  Try this approach  */
    const myNewData = req.body;
    await MyCollectionName.findByIdAndUpdate( myNewData._id , {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      etc: req.body.etc
    },
    {new: true} 

  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
  }

})
```

Note: set the option `new` to `true` to get the new version of the doc